# I Deleted an employee data from emp table by using below user defined function and then tried to roll back it but couldn't get the data back

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, delete-row, rollback

```
create or replace function delete_EMP
(
    PENO IN NUMBER
)
return varchar2 as
VNAME VARCHAR2(20);
begin
    SELECT ENAME INTO VNAME FROM EMP WHERE EMPNO=PENO;
    DELETE FROM EMP WHERE EMPNO=PENO;
  return VNAME;
end;
```

Also how do i run this function in select statement,

Answer (score 4):

You can't call a function that makes changes to data in a `select` statement (well, not unless you declare it to use an autonomous transaction but that's almost always a bad idea).  That's why you generally wouldn't write a function that deletes data.  If you need to delete data, you'd want a procedure.

As for why your rollback didn't work, I'd guess that you did a commit first either explicitly or because your tool/ program is set to autocommit

Comment: It's probably too late for OP at this point. But for future reference Oracle provides the ability to 'rollback' after a 'commit'. This is accomplished through their [Flashback](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28424/adfns_flashback.htm#g1026131) capability. Provided your DBA has configured it.